# spring security manual login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using spring security and want to login my users manually.

my controller looks like this:

```
 @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        Authentication authenticationResult = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("user2", "password"));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationResult);
        return "redirect:/";
}
```

I found an example in the docs where such a login is made.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#what-is-authentication-in-spring-security

I just wanted to ask whether there are any downsides or security issues with this approach?

**EDIT:**
If someone can point me to the class (&docs?) where the default spring /login request ist handled it might also answer my question as i could look how the login process is implemented spring internally

Comment: I used this approach with JSF, because I used a custom jsf login page that calls my own ManagedBean, and this is what I do into login action. I think this is not risky.

Comment: Taking the example literally, of course it makes no sense to hard code the user and password.

Comment: Of course i wouldn't hatdcode the credentials, this was just for a test wether this login would work

Comment: And it worked in terms of that i could access urls which where secured

Comment: Why do you want to login your users manually... Why workaround a framework designed for security?

Comment: I just want to be able to login users manually/ better understand what happens behind the scenes

Comment: Please look at my edit of the question

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around when we need to do some process before the user logs in. 
The actual problem comes when you do the following things. Of course these are not problems :-).

1. If You are using spring remember-me token or custom authentication providers.
2. When you are using encrypted passwords in your DB.